# Клонировал репозиторий но не могу запустить его с помощью npm start. Как исправить?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-26T18_05_56_020Z-debug.log

Comment: проверьте, есть ли данный скрип в `package.json`

Comment: модули установили yarn install или npm install ?